# authorization Callbacks does not work for private channels in laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I succeed to implement a realtime notifications in laravel via Pusher.

For that I follow all instructions described in laravel documentations.

This is my `BroadcastServiceProvider` :

```
public function boot ()
        {
            Broadcast::routes();


            Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
                return (int)$user->user_id === (int)$userId;
            });

        }
```

And below is Javascript codes to fire events:

```
var pusher  = new Pusher("xxxxxxxxxxxxx",{
                auth: {
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-Token': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
                    }
                }
            });
            var channel = pusher.subscribe('private-App.User.{{$AuthUser->user_id}}');
            channel.bind('Illuminate\\Notifications\\Events\\BroadcastNotificationCreated', function (data) {
                alert(data);
            });
```

All things works properly.

But for test I returned `false` inside `Broadcast::channel('App.User.*',` like this :

```
Broadcast::channel('App.User.*', function ($user, $userId) {
        return false;
});
```

But I do not know what does this part of the Code while return a true or false value Does not have any effect on its performance.

what does exactly here?

Comment: Returning true or false in a channel call basically says 'is the user allowed to listen to this channel?'. By returning false you are saying no, they are not, so it won't fire the call.

Comment: But while `return false` all things work and user can receive notifs from that Channel.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? please share! I have a similar problem now.